# FolderBrowseDialog to browse folder of server computer from client computer

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

I want to open the *directory* of *server computer* using `FolderBrowserDialog` from the *client machine.*
Is it possible?

I have searched for it n haven't found the solution.

> I have found others such as to browse *Network Folders*, here: [How-to-Browse-Network-Folders-using-Folder-Dialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20547/How-to-Browse-Network-Folders-using-Folder-Dialog) .
>
> But i am looking for to browse the *directory* of *server* from the *client*.

Comment: if I am not mistaken your own link explains just that - just remember to start with `\\serverhostname` and the rest should work just as you are used to (of course your IT should be contacted - you need certain rights and folders have to be shared - yeah there are administrator-shares for each local drive on windows - like `\\servername\c$` but most likely they won't give you those ;))

Comment: @Carsten : I am naive on this. I don't know how to solve it. As you said, first the administrator should share folder or drive and then can only be browse to that folder from client, right?Anyway i have learned some.

Comment: yeah on windows you can just use it as `\\servername\sharedFolderName` - and if you point your dialogs `SelectedPath` property to this I think it should work as expected (the user should start his exploration right there at the server)

Comment: but that is exactly what's explained in your link ;) - as mentioned there you should probably set the `RootFolder` to `NetworkShortcuts` (I think this will work in .net 4 - if not you'll have to do the hack from the article using value 18)

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet that works fine with .net 4:

```
Dim dlg As New FolderBrowserDialog()
dlg.SelectedPath = "\\yourServer\share"

If dlg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim selected = dlg.SelectedPath
    ' ...
End If
```

no need for `RootFolder` or any hacking - this will open the dialog on my computer (both client/server are windows-OS in a windows-domain) at the network-share and let my trill down into the folders there - at the end you will get a string like `\\yourServer\share\selected\path` back

Comment: It will take some time for me. Later, I will try it n let u know. Anyway thank you for giving time n effort.